# Failure of 1st welfare theorem with non-increasing utility function

Tags: utility, general-equilibrium

I want to find an example that utility function is not increasing
but still satisfies that $u(x) \geq u(y)$ for all $x \geq y$
and 1st welfare theorem fails.
I want to prove this on edgeworth box not using mathematical process.

Non-increasing(non-monotonic) utility function is related to non-satiation properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following may work.

Let there be two consumers. Consumer 1 has standard (convex, continuous, strictly increasing) and let consumer 2 have constant utility (i.e. indifferent between any two consumption bundles). This still satisfies your condition.

Then given some endowments, and arbitrary prices, let consumer 1 maximize her utility. Then consumer 2 will (by definition) also maximize his utility as he is indifferent between anything. This will then give a competitive equilibrium.

The only Pareto efficient equilibrium, however, is when consumer 1 has all the endowments, which will usually not be the case.

Comment: I can't understand what exactly "consumer 2 has constant utility" means. What I thought is goods 2 is neutral to consumer 2 so his indifferent curve is vertical. Is that the same what you mean?

Comment: @guest No I meant that consumer 2 is indifferent between any two bundles. This means that he has constant utility function, e.g. $u(x) = 0$ for all consumption bundles $x$. His indifference curve is the entire consumption space.

Comment: I got it, and one more question. A vertical indifference curve also satisfies above condition too?

Comment: yes. As long as indifference curves are not upward sloping, or inverted (i.e. they look normal but less is better), you should be good.